# Suppose a group G has no proper subgroups (that is, the only subgroup of G is G itself and the trivial subgroup {e}. Show that G is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose a group G has no proper subgroups (that is, the only subgroup of G is G itself and the trivial subgroup {e}. Show that G is cyclic.

how to solve the question?

Comment: Consider the subgroup generated by a non-identity element $g \in G$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

If $G=\{e\}$ then we are done. Now assume that there's $G\ni g\ne e$. What's the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g$?

Comment: Nope. This can't prove that the group $G$ is finite.

Answer (score -1):

if you Let G be a group with no proper, nontrivial subgroups.let g be a non
-trivial element of G then  Consider < g >,the cyclic subgroup generated by g.
This is a subgroup of G, but since the only subgroups of G are < e >and
G, < g >=< e >or < g >= G. But we assumed g was nontrivial.
So< g > not equal< e > :Thus, < g >= G:But this means G is generated by
< g >

Comment: Can you show that the group generated by $g$ is finite?

Answer (score -1):

If $e$ is the only element of $G$, then $\langle e \rangle = G$ and therefore $G$ is cyclic. Otherwise, let $a$ be a
nonidentity element of $G$. Then either $\langle a \rangle = \{e\}$, which is impossible as $a \notin \langle e \rangle$, or $\langle a \rangle = G$, which implies that $G$ is cyclic.